# Django runserver_plus Werkzeug not installed error, although it is

Tags: ssl-certificate, werkzeug, django-errors, django-extensions, django-runserver

I am trying to run my Django application using runserver_plus as I am using an SSL certificate to create HTTPS connections to the backend.
In order to do so, I have done the following:

1. pip install django_extensions
2. Installed Django extensions to the project but include
   "django_extensions" in the "INSTALLED_APPS" list in the settings.py
   file.
3. pip install Werkzeug
4. python -m pip freeze (to make sure everything has been installed
   correctly within the venv)
5. ran ./manage.py to check the available commands (to make sure Django
   extensions is working as expected)

However, I get the following error:

```
CommandError: Werkzeug is required to use runserver_plus.
```

although everything has been installed properly and all checks/re-installs have been made. Also, it must be noted that I updated Django, django_extensions, and Werkzeug to the latest versions available.

Answer (score 3):

This is a recurrent issue with Werkzeug. Your safest option is to downgrade to 0.16.1.

Comment: This worked for me! Tried several versions of Werkzeug and 0.16.1 is what worked.